# ESXi 6.7 web UI, what is CPU "Package 0" in the monitor page?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an ESXi 6.7 lab, with i9-10900. From the Web UI Host - Monitor - Performance tab page, what is CPU "**Package 0**"? The value isn't the same as host CPU usage%. Googled, but I can't find what it is.
It seem to be the reading of the Socket 0 CPU usage.. (I don't have a dual CPU server to check)
Then, what is the host CPU reading for? The load of the hypervisor? Any link to an official doc?